# invalid stream header: CAFEBABE exception in applet while reading from database through java code

Tags: java, applet, jdbc-odbc

I am try to get some info from database and show it on applet . for that i am setting connection and getting data through another class then transfer it to the applet but in applet code when i set inputstream to that class file then i am getting this exception :-

```
Exception Found :- java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: CAFEBABE
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: CAFEBABE
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at examapplet.init(examapplet.java:118)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

this is my applet code :-

```
    URL url1=new URL(getDocumentBase(),"getLang.class");
    System.out.println(""+url1);
    URLConnection urc1=url1.openConnection();
    ObjectInputStream ois1=new ObjectInputStream(urc1.getInputStream()); // exception line
    String lang=(String)ois1.readObject();
    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(lang,"@");
    langc=new Choice();
    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
            langc.addItem(st.nextToken());
    }
    ois1.close();
    langc.addItemListener(this);
    langc.setBounds(200,120,100,30);
    add(langc);
```

And This Is my getLang class

```
   import java.io.*;
   import javax.servlet.*;
   import javax.servlet.http.*;
   import java.sql.*;
   public class getLang extends HttpServlet
   {
   Connection con=null;
   Statement st=null;
   ResultSet rs=null;
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException,ServletException
   {
    try
    {           
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:online");
    st=con.createStatement();
    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from msubjectinfo");
    String lang="";
    while(rs.next())
    {
          lang+= rs.getString(2) + "@";
    }
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(res.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeObject(lang);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            System.out.println("Exception Found :--"+e);
    }
   }
   }
```

How Can I solve this Or Tell Me any other way to retrieve the string ??

Comment: It looks like you are reading a "class" file using ObjectInputStream, not a serialized string. All class files start with the 32-bit number 0xCAFEBABE. If you hit that URL in a browser, are you getting a string as expected? Are you deploying your servlet in a container?

Comment: so how can i get that data from servlet to applet . any other way ?

Comment: You can do what you did. But just make sure to use the URL of the servlet, and not `getLang.class`, which is not the URL of the servlet, but the URL of a class file.

Comment: thx for solving my confusion now its working